# Why in general $U(n)$ can be found by exponentiating but $O(n)$ cannot?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $U(n), O(n)$ be the matrix groups of dimension $n$ such that, for some element in one of these groups $A$, $AA^\dagger=\mathbb{I}$. Note $O(n)\subset GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ and $U(n)\subset GL(n,\mathbb{C})$. My book states:

> One can show that $U(n)$ and $u(n)$ matrices can be diagonalized by conjugation by a unitary matrix and thus show that any $U(n)$ matrix can be written as
> an exponential of something in the Lie algebra. The corresponding theorem is
> also true for $SO(n)$ but requires looking at diagonalization into 2 by 2 blocks. It
> is not true for $O(n)$ (you can’t reach the disconnected component of the identity
> by exponentiation).

Since the elements in $U(n)$ are defined over a complex field, then the diagonalization always exists and I can believe that for $A\in U(n)$, $A=\exp(tX)$, where $t$ is real and $X$ is a component in the corresponding Lie algebra.

On the other hand, since $O(n)\subset GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ I can buy that some eigenvalues are not real numbers but... Is it not true that $O(n)\subset U(n)$, or at least that $O(n)\subset GL(n,\mathbb{C})$? Can someone give an example of a $B\in O(n)$ with $B\notin U(n)$?

Comment: The point is that you can't reach an orthogonal matrix like $\operatorname{diag}(1, -1)$ via exponentiating a real matrix, since one eigenvalue is negative and exponentials of real matrices have positive eigenvalues. On the other hand one could exponentiate the complex matrix $\operatorname{diag}(0, \pi i)$ to get $\operatorname{diag}(1, -1)$.

Comment: But why not to start with $O(n)\subset U(n)$ over a complex field from the beginning? Are the matrices which are orthogonal but not unitary?

Comment: Consider what happens when $n = 1$: $SO(1) = \{1\}$ is the identity matrix; $O(1) = \{-1, 1\}$ is a set of two matrices; $U(1) = \{e^{it} : \text{$t$ real}\}$. We can't "reach" the non-identity component $-1$ by a continuous path in $O(1)$, but we _can_ reach $-1$ by exponentiating within $U(1)$. <> If that doesn't help, more care may be needed with the definitions of $O(n) \subset U(n) \subset O(2n)$ inside $GL(n, \mathbf{R}) \subset GL(n, \mathbf{C}) \subset GL(2n, \mathbf{R})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in some Lie group, you can write an element $g$ as $\exp(X)$ for $X$ in the Lie algebra of $G$, then $c(t):=\exp(tX)$ gives you a smooth curve in $G$ that connects the unit element $e$ to $g$. In case of $G=O(n)$, this means that $\det(c(t))=\pm 1$, so this has to be constant and since $\det(e)=1$ the curve has to stay in $O(n)$. If you include $O(n)$ into $U(n)$ you see that you can write an element of $O(n)$ as the exponential of a skew Hermitian matrix but not of a skew symmetric. This is no contradition, since for a curve in $U(n)$ the determinant can be non-constant. Just look at the simplest example that $\exp\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & i\pi\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$.